# problem with list return type?

Tags: python

my list has value such as

```
m=[['na','1','2']['ka','31','45']['ra','3','5']

d=0
r=2

t=m[d][r]
print t         # this is givin number i.e 2
```

Now when I use this value

```
u=[]
u=m[t]
```

I am getting an err msg saying type error list does take str values...

i want to use like this how can i convert that t into a integer??

please suggest..

thanks..

Comment: You have unbalanced square brackets in your code. Copy + paste error?

Comment: I think the variable m should be m = [['na','1','2'],['ka','31','45'],['ra','3','5']], isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't index into a list using a string. To convert `t` to an integer use `int`:

```
u=m[int(t)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `int(t)` as the index, not `t` itself, since `t` is a string and to index a variable you need an integer, **not** a string, as the error message is telling you.